# Maximizing perimeter of rectangle in a given problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

> The lengths of the sides of a rectangle are all integers. Four times its perimeter is numerically equal to one less than its area. Find the largest perimeter of such a rectangle.

What's a proper solution for the problem above?

Given we're working with both an unknown perimeter and area, is it necessary to use calculus or is there another method?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: let $m$ and $n$ be the side lengths. Then you know that
$$
mn=8(m+n)+1\iff (m-8)(n-8)=65.
$$
There are not that many integers that satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b$ be the side lengths of the rectangle. The perimeter of the rectangle is $2(a+b)$ and the area is $ab$. Thus, we wish to solve the Diophantine equation $8(a+b)=ab-1$, subject to the constraints $a,b>0$ and maximizing $a+b$. Graphing this curve on the plane or otherwise, it is easy to see that there are only finitely many solutions. The solutions are: $(a,b)=(9,73), (13,21)$ and their reflections across the line $a=b$. In particular, the largest perimeter must be $2(9+73)=164$